# Regular Expression in a single function

Tags: javascript, html

I have done some regular expression validation, here is the below what i did,

Javascript:

```
function fn1() {
var var1=/^(\s*|\d+)$/ 
if (document.myform.inp1.value.search(var1)==-1) {
alert("validation for digits failed")
}
}

function fn2() {
var var2=/^(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{2})?|\d+(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?)$/ 
if (document.myform.inp2.value.search(var2)==-1) {
alert("validation for currency failed")
}
}

function fn3() {
var var3=/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/ 
if (document.myform.inp3.value.search(var3)==-1) {
alert("validation for date failed")
}
}
</script>
```

Below is my HTML,

```
<form name="myform">
<div id="div1">

<input type="text" name="inp1"  />
<input type="button" onClick="fn1()" value="chk1"/>
</div>

<div id="div2">

<input type="text" name="inp2" />
<input type="button" onClick="fn2()" value="chk2" />
</div>

<div id="div3">

<input type="text" name="inp3" />
<input type="button" onClick="fn3()" value="chk3" />
</div>

</form>
```

Now i need to combine all this into a single function which should accept the regular expression as a parameter. so there should be one JavaScript function which accepts three arguments (`<<selector for input field>>, <<regular Expression>>, <<Error message>>`). Please help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function expression(selector, regex, error) {
    if (selector.value.search(regex)==-1) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

`selector` would have to be something along the lines of `document.myform.inp1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this;

```
function checkItem(elem, regex, errMsg) {
    if (elem.value.search(regex) == -1) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
checkItem(document.myform.inp1, /^(\s*|\d+)$/, "validation for digits failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

First put your validation functions into an object:

```
var validationFunctions = {
    digits: function (val) {
        ... fn1 here ...
    },
    currency: function (val) {
        ... fn2 here ...
    },
    date: function (val) {
        ... fn3 here ...
    }
};
```

Then your generic function would look something like this:

```
var validate = function (elementID, type) {
    var value = document.getElementById(elementID).value;

    return validationFunctions[type](value);
};
```

You'd call it like this:

```
validate('inputBoxID', 'digits');
validate('inputBoxID', 'currency');
validate('inputBoxID', 'date');
```